# What's the difference between using or not using the 'where' clause with generics?

Tags: swift, generics

What's the difference between these two methods of declaring a generics superclass with or without the 'where' clause?

```
func foo<T: SomeClass>(object: T) -> Array<T>

func foo<T>(object: T) -> Array<T> where T: SomeClass
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is clearly stated in the [Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html):

> The requirements in a generic where clause specify that a type
>   parameter inherits from a class or conforms to a protocol or protocol
>   composition. Although the generic where clause provides syntactic
>   sugar for expressing simple constraints on type parameters (for
>   instance, `<T: Comparable>` is equivalent to `<T> where T: Comparable` and
>   so on), you can use it to provide more complex constraints on type
>   parameters and their associated types. For instance, you can constrain
>   the associated types of type parameters to conform to protocols. For
>   example, `<S: Sequence> where S.Iterator.Element: Equatable` specifies
>   that `S` conforms to the `Sequence` protocol and that the associated type
>   `S.Iterator.Element` conforms to the `Equatable` protocol. This constraint
>   ensures that each element of the sequence is equatable.

Simply put, `where` lets you specify constraints about the associated types of a generic parameter, while in `<>` you can't do this.

Answer (score 3):

Questions like these always require some practical examples, even the simplest to get basic idea. Otherwise it often remains theoretical.

As referenced by Sweeper, that which is after `where` is called type constraint. Typically you specify one or more protocols which introduce conditions which must be met by passed object or a type. And as mentioned, it's only after `where` where you can specify `associatedtype` constraint of the generic type.

Consider the following example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype AType

    func foo()
}

class MyClassInt : NSObject, MyProtocol {
    typealias AType = Int

    func foo() {
        print(type(of: self))
    }
}

class MyClassString : NSObject, MyProtocol {
    typealias AType = String

    func foo() {
        print("I'm not implemented")
    }
}

extension MyProtocol where Self.AType == Int {
    func test() {
        self.foo()
    }
}
```

Now check our things:

```
let str = MyClassString()
str.test() // Won't compile !!
```

> 'MyClassString.AType' (aka 'String') is not convertible to 'Int'

This one compiles and runs:

```
let int = MyClassInt()
int.test()
```

In this example we have a protocol with the `associatedtype` specified. And there's also an `extension` which is only applied to our `MyProtocol` with particular `associatedtype`, in our case `Int`. That extension defines single method. As you can see, compiler won't let us to call that method with the `associatedtype` other than that specified by a constraint, even though `MyClassString` also implements that protocol.