# Is there a practical difference between a type constraint on a generic type directly vs using a 'where' clause?

Tags: swift, generics, constraints, generic-constraints

Is there any practical difference in capabilities between these two functions?

```
func testX<T>(value:T) where T:StringProtocol {
    // Do something
}

func testY<T:StringProtocol>(value:T){
    // Do something
}
```

They both seem to compile and run just fine. Wondering why there's two different, but seemingly identical syntaxes.

Comment: There is no difference. The first form was introduce with https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/78332d211d00abac286c47609ce1a88a03c6e9bf/proposals/0081-move-where-expression.md to increase readability, in particular for longer lists of constraints.

Comment: Mind putting that in an answer, not a comment? :)

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/46810009/2976878

Comment: @Hamish: Should we close this as a duplicate? (I had searched for SE-0081 before answering, without success)

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, I think so. Although note that this would have still been a valid question even before SE-0081, e.g "what's the difference between `<T : StringProtocol>` and `<T where T : StringProtocol>`?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. The first form

```
func testX<T>(value: T) where T: StringProtocol
```

was introduced with [SE-0081 Move where clause to end of declaration](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/78332d211d00abac286c47609ce1a88a03c6e9bf/proposals/0081-move-where-expression.md) to increase readability, in particular for longer lists of constraints. The rationale was to remove the `where` clause out of the generic parameter list, for example

```
func foo<S: Sequence where S.Element == Int>(seq: S)
```

became

```
func foo<S: Sequence>(seq: S) where S.Element == Int
```

in Swift 3. As a side-effect, even simple constraints such as
your `T: StringProtocol` can be moved to the newly introduced where-clause.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted, but I'm not sure that's an exact match as that post talks about moving the 'where' clause from before the signature to after it, but here, I don't have a 'where' clause in the latter case, just the normal type constraint.  Still, they're definitely related so as I said, I'll accept yours as the answer.

Comment: @MarqueIV: As it turns out, this has been asked before. If you un-accept the answer then I can delete it.

Comment: There's no down-side to leaving this here because it's good information. No need to delete in my book. :)