# What is the difference between these two methods of declaring generic constraints?

Tags: swift, generics

Is there any functional difference between defining a generic constraint like this:

```
func compare<T: Comparable>(l: T, r: T) -> Bool {
   return l == r
}
```

or with a where clause like this:

```
func compare<T>(l: T, r: T) -> Bool where T: Comparable {
   return l == r
}
```

I see examples of both in the Swift docs and both compile properly.  So which should I use & when?

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID192

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46810009/3141234 looks like an exact match. Let me know if you have any other questions